# weird formatting result in rails app

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have the following partial to display some stuff. However, the page renders with one element on the first row, 3 on the next, etc. The last row has 2 elements. So essentially, there is a shift. Any reason this could be happening?

```
<% @albums.each_with_index do |album, i| %> 
    <%if i==0 || i==3 || i==6 || i==9 %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">

            <% if album["image"][2]["#text"] != nil %>
            <img class="img-circle" src="<%= album["image"][2]["#text"] %>"  width="140" height="140">
            <% else %>
            <img class="img-circle" src="<%= image_path("rec.png") %>"  width="140" height="140">
            <% end %>


            <h2><%= album["name"] %></h2>
            <p>
                <strong>BY: </strong><%= album["artist"] %><br>
                <div>
                <%= form_tag(:action => "add_album") do %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'album_name', album["name"] %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'album_artist', album["artist"] %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'album_id', album["id"] %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'album_image', album["image"][2]["#text"]%>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'album_image_large', album["image"][3]["#text"] %>
                <%= submit_tag("Add") %>
                <% end %>
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <%else%>
    <div class="col-lg-4">

        <% if album["image"][2]["#text"] != nil %>
        <img class="img-circle" src="<%= album["image"][2]["#text"] %>"  width="140" height="140">
        <% else %>
        <img class="img-circle" src="<%= image_path("rec.png") %>"  width="140" height="140">
        <% end %>       

        <h2><%= album["name"] %></h2>
        <p>
            <strong>BY: </strong><%= album["artist"] %><br>
            <div>
                <%= form_tag(:action => "add_album") do %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'album_name', album["name"] %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'album_artist', album["artist"] %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'album_id', album["id"] %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'album_image', album["image"][2]["#text"]%>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'album_image_large', album["image"][3]["#text"] %>
                <%= submit_tag("Add") %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </p>
    </div>
    <%end%>


<% end %>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have always row defined? You only have it defined for `true`, you should take it out of the test, before the first `if`

Comment: div class row should be after the first if statement as Ruby Racer states.

Comment: The thing is, there are supposed to be 3 elements per row, so the idea is that a row is initialized every three elements, and if a row should not be initialized, the else statement is accessed and just a column is made instead

Comment: Oh, I think i need to have the test just determine whether there is a row or not